# how format factor Hour and Minute as time in R

Tags: r

is there a way to format below data points as Time in R without any date associated with them. For example,

df

Time
00:00
00:15
00:30
00:45

if I do,

```
    Df$Time<-as.POSIXct(df$Time, format="%H:%M")
```

it turns into as below:

```
2013-04-26 00:00:00 EDT
2013-04-26 00:15:15 EDT
```

Comment: `format(Sys.time(),"%H:%M")` -> `[1] "18:28"`

Comment: @haki, the final number is becomes class character. I need it to be class time.

Comment: you asked how to format date to display the time. your `df$Time` object stores the time - what do you want to do with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely a better way but...

```
x <-factor(c('00:00', '00:15', '00:30', '00:45'))

library(chron)
times(paste0("00:", as.character(x)))
```