# R Extract Hours from Time in factor Format

Tags: r

I have a vector of time that is in the format of factor. For instance, Time[1] is 8:01:01, class(Time[1]) is factor.

Now I want to extract hours and minute from this vector. What is the most computational efficient way of doing it? My vector is very large. Thank you so much,

Comment: Dirk's approach worked for me - Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348992/convert-factor-to-date-time-in-r                                                                                                                                              or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239646/how-format-factor-hour-and-minute-as-time-in-r

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
format(strptime(Time,"%H:%M:%S"),'%H:%M')
[1] "08:01"
```

Answer (score 17):

One way with the `lubridate` package would be:

```
Time <- factor("08:01:01")
lubridate::hms(as.character(Time))
```

### Edit

To extract hours and minutes:

```
library(lubridate)
Time <- factor("08:01:01")

# parese date
a <- hms(as.character(Time))

# get hours
hour(a)

# get minutes
minute(a)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. How do you get the actual hours and minutes after applying hms though? Thanks,

Comment: Thank you so much. I will test them to see which is fastest.

Answer (score 10):

You could also try a combination of converting your factor to a POSIXt object and then using the format function. I'm not sure how efficient this method is though.

```
Time <- factor("08:01:01")
hour = format(as.POSIXct(Time,format="%H:%M:%S"),"%H")
minute = format(as.POSIXct(Time,format="%H:%M:%S"),"%M")

paste(hour,minute,sep=":")
[1] "08:01"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's the current method I'm using. I was hoping to make it faster though.

Comment: maybe try the chron package. `require(chron)` `times(Time,out.format="h:m")`. The only problem with this method is that the hour and minutes aren't separated by a colon. output: `[1] 0801`. But maybe this will speed things up for you.

Answer (score 5):

What about this

```
 Time  <- factor("08:01:01")
 Time2 <- strptime(Time, "%H:%M:%S")
 Time3 <- format(Time2, "%H:%M")
```

Time3

[1] "08:01"

Answer (score 4):

Simpler solution:
`format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M")`

Answer (score 3):

The `data.table` package handles date times. You could use its convenience functions `hour()` and `minute()` to extract specific times and `paste0()` them together.

```r
require(data.table)
time = Sys.time()
paste0(hour(time), ':', minute(time))
```